# Unable to send Email with assigment rules

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

I'm attempting to send a email alert via apex. Following is my code..

```
global class myARules{ 

public static void processMe(Set<Id> RIds) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] mainlist = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{};                 
    List<Lead> myList = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Id IN: RIds];

    for (Lead l: myList) {

        myCSSettings__c cs = myCSSettings__c.getInstance(l.code__c);
        List<Group> Groupees = [SELECT Id, Email from Group where id = : cs.id__c];
        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;// use leadAssignment rules when updating
        l.setOptions(dmo);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {Groupees[0].Email}; 
        Id templateId = [select id, name from EmailTemplate where developername = :Label.myEmailTemplte].id;
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
        mail.setTargetObjectId(Groupees[0].Id);
        mail.setTemplateId(templateId);  
        mainlist.add(mail);                          
    }
     system.debug('@@mainlist'+mainlist);    
     system.debug('@@mainlistsize'+mainlist.size());     

    try{     
             system.debug('@@myList'+myList);
             update(myList);
          Messaging.sendEmail(mainlist);           
    } 

    catch (DmlException e){
            system.debug('@@Exception: '+e); 
    }
}
}
```

I am able to do all tasks except sending a mail. Assignment rules are firing as per requirement. Debug says **@@mainlistsize** is 0.

Also, a mail is sent if this **for-loop** is not present --> **for (Lead l: myList)**

I will be thankful if someone can point me to the right directin. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You declared the variable as **maillist** and adding the **mail** to **mainlist**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs

> setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId)
>
> Required if using a template, optional otherwise. The ID of the **contact, lead, or user** to which the email will be sent. The ID you specify sets the context and ensures that merge fields in the template contain the correct data.

However you are passing in the Id of a Group

```
List<Group> Groupees = [SELECT Id, Email from Group where id = : cs.id__c];
...
mail.setTargetObjectId(Groupees[0].Id);
```

Comment: I will ask a separate question because I don't want the email notification to be sent to this settargetobjectid's email, which is now sending.